# How to sort a Hashmap on Key based on Custom Comparator

Tags: sorting, collections, java-8, custom-compare

I am receiving a Hashmap for a common process that I need to sort on the Key using a custom comparator.

Below is what I have tried, but it does not seem to work - it is not sorting the keys.

The keys of the map are of the form long-string-short ***Example:( 11169-SW-1 / 11169-SW-2 / 11132-SH-2 / 11132-SH-7 / 11132-SH-1 )***.  The string compare doesn't work as I need it for the numeric part, so I have a custom comparator defined.  I realise that the custom comparator code needs to be cleaned-up - e.g. multiple return statements need to be consolidated and othe clean-up needs to happen, but I can do that once I get it to work.

How can I do it?

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> strValuesMap = Utilities.getDataMapFromDB();

Map<String, Map<String, String>> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(new CustomComparator());
sortedMap.putAll(strValuesMap);
sortedMap.forEach((x, y) -> System.out.println("id " + x + "=" + y));
```

The custom comparator is defined as below

```
class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String plId1, String plId2) {

        System.out.println("plId1 : " + plId1 + " plId2 " + plId2);
        String[] plId1Split = plId1.split("-");
        String[] plId2Split = plId2.split("-");
        int retValue = 0;
        if (!plId1Split[0].equalsIgnoreCase(plId2Split[0])) {
            Long seq1 = new Long(plId1Split[0]);
            Long seq2 = new Long(plId2Split[0]);
            retValue = seq1.compareTo(seq1);
        }
        if (retValue != 0) {
            return retValue;
        }
        if (!plId1Split[1].equalsIgnoreCase(plId2Split[1])) {
            retValue = plId1.compareTo(plId2);
        }
        if (retValue != 0) {
            return retValue;
        } else {
            Short seq1 = new Short(plId1Split[2]);
            Short seq2 = new Short(plId2Split[2]);
            retValue = seq1.compareTo(seq2);
            return retValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure : your comparator is set to sort the keys of the first level map, not the second one. Is it your requirement ?

Comment: @davidxxx - Yes, the first level map.  I think, when defining the comparator with the TreeMap, I need to indicate that, right? But not sure how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct:

```
if (!plId1Split[1].equalsIgnoreCase(plId2Split[1])) {
    retValue = plId1.compareTo(plId2); // This part is wrong
}
```

In the conditional body, you should compare only the second part of the strings(`plId1Split[1]` with `plId2Split[1]`) while you compare the whole strings (`plId1` with `plId2`).
So it means the last part of the strings (`plId1Split[2]` and `plId2Split[2]`) are not compared according to a numerical order but a lexicographical order.

So it should be :

```
if (!plId1Split[1].equalsIgnoreCase(plId2Split[1])) {
    retValue = plId1Split[1].compareTo(plId2Split[1]);
}
```

About the clarity of your comparator I think that some of your tests are not required.
For example you compare with `equalsIgnoreCase()` and you compare then with long comparator the same string converted to long :

```
if (!plId1Split[0].equalsIgnoreCase(plId2Split[0])) {
        Long seq1 = new Long(plId1Split[0]);
        Long seq2 = new Long(plId2Split[0]);
        retValue = seq1.compareTo(seq1);
}
```

It not a great optimization, overall if the two comparisons are invoked and it also makes the code less readable.

Note also that you overuse number objects which here produce undesirable boxing operations (`Long`->`long`) that have a cost.
You could write something like :

```
class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String plId1, String plId2) {

        String[] plId1Split = plId1.split("-");
        String[] plId2Split = plId2.split("-");

        int retValue = Long.compare(Long.parseLong(plId1Split[0]), 
                               Long.parseLong(plId2Split[0]));

        if (retValue != 0) {
            return retValue;
        }

        retValue = plId1Split[1].compareTo(plId2Split[1]);

        if (retValue != 0) {
            return retValue;
        }

        return Short.compare(Short.parseShort(plId1Split[2]), 
                       Short.parseShort(plId2Split[2]));

   }                    
}
```

---

As alternative you could use Java 8 Comparators by relying on a custom class representing the object to compare :

```
// private package if makes sense to make this class not visible outside that
class Identifier {
    private long part1;
    private String part2;
    private short part3;

    Identifier(String[] split) {
        this.part1 =  Long.parseLong(split[0]);
        this.part2 =  split[1];
        this.part3 =  Short.parseShort(split[2]);
    }

    long getPart1() {
        return part1;
    }    
    String getPart2() {
        return part2;
    }
    short getPart3() {
        return part3;
    }
}
```

And use [`public static <T, U> Comparator<T> comparing(
            Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor,
            Comparator<? super U> keyComparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-)

that extracts a sort key to compare elements and applies a specified comparator for this sort key :

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;
import static java.util.Comparator.comparingLong;

Comparator<String> comp =
        comparing(s -> new Identifier(s.split("-")),
                  comparingLong(Identifier::getPart1)
                 .thenComparing(Identifier::getPart2)
                 .thenComparingInt(Identifier::getPart3));
```

It exposes clearly the comparing/functional logic.

Note that since Java doesn't provide built-in structures for Tuple, we are required to introduce a custom class to hold data.
With tuple classes (coming from https://www.javatuples.org/ or any source code) the code would be still simpler.

Comment: Hi, thanks for spotting that. But now I am running into other problem.  The original map has more than 4000 rows whereas my new map has only 50 rows.

_strValuesMap size 4444_   and   
_sortedMap size 50_

Comment: Yeah - I knew I had to rewrite the comparator.  Thanks for giving the pointers for those.  But still not sure why the sizes of the two maps do not match

Comment: There must have been some other issue with my comparator.  When I replaced it with the changes you had, it is now returning the map with 4444 rows and correctly sorted.

Comment: You are welcome. It is very likely. Verbose code produce often typing error not necessarily easy to spot. I updated with a Java 8 way. It may also be interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate Java 8 way too.   That also worked well and it is more compact and concise as well.